# Azure: How do I fix this Error when Creating Service Principle?

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, service-principal, azure-service-principal

I'm new-ish to Azure.  I'm following along with a Pluralsight tutorial to learn how to programmatically access an Azure Media Service with c#, and it's telling me to create a Service Principle.

I'm using this command in Visual Studio Developer Powershell:

```
az ams account sp create -a mymediaservice -g mymediaservice --subscription MY_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME
```

Yes, my resource group name matches my media service name.  Different from the tutorial, I had to add the subscription name to the command, because the default subscription didn't match the subscription I'm trying to work in.

I get this error:

```
Values of identifierUris property must use a verified domain of the organization or its subdomain: 'http://mymediaservice-access-sp'
```

Can anyone explain this in a simplified way, telling me step by step how to get this done?

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version of the cli installed, try `az upgrade`

Comment: @PeterBons WOW, I think that may have worked.  How did you know this was a possibility?

Comment: I had the same problem a week ago 

Comment: @PeterBons It looks like it did work.  If you want credit, write up your comment as a quick answer and I'll accept it.  Met Dank.

Comment: graag gedaan ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen if you run an older version of the Azure Cli. I had the same problem a week ago and managed to solve it by updating the cli using this command:

```
az upgrade
```